# How to avoid layouts to change their size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt4, pyqt4

I set a QMainWindow with two layouts, called A and B, in a Pyqt4 app written in Python 3.5

They usually display as shown in this schema:

[image: Good display]

But at some point, something in Layout B makes wider. Therefore Layout B makes wider too, overlapping Layout A, which remain partially hidden:

[image: Wrong display]

Could anybody please give me a hand to find a solution to this behaviour?
I would like to lock Layout A and B widths somehow to avoid this issue.

Comment: You can provide a [mcve] to understand your problem.

Comment: Please give minimum and maximum size for both the layout. Also provide your GUI min and max size.. I think your GUI max size is smaller than your layout size.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I suspect you add both layouts directly to your main window, without putting them into a main layout that would control their resizing. This way you're creating unnecessary problems, as you need to manage the layout's position and size manually. [Read more in the Qt docs.](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/layout.html)

To solve this, you just add a [`QHBoxLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qhboxlayout.html) to the main window, then the child layouts to that using [`addLayout()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addLayout) with an appropriate stretch factor. Here's an example in C++ (untested) to illustrate the necessary steps:

```
QHBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout();

QGridLayout* childLayout0 = new QGridLayout();
QGridLayout* childLayout1 = new QGridLayout();

//Add widgets to the child layouts

mainLayout->addLayout(childLayout0, 2);
mainLayout->addLayout(childLayout1, 1);

mainWindow->setLayout(mainLayout);
```